# How to properly set up multi profile maven project?

Tags: java, maven, profiles

Hey, I'm talking about profiles within pom.xml of a project. Could please anybody explain to me, why if I have 2 profiles in pom definition and I run test phase from one of the profiles, both the Main method is executed and all the tests are run by surefire plugin ? I mean, even the surefire plugin runs all the tests, even though it is within a different profile ?

```
mvn test -Pcode-generator
```

the first one,code-generator, is just for Main methods execution and the second one for the rest of the project.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>code-generator</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>cz.instance.transl.Main</mainClass>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>arg0</argument>
                                    <argument>arg1</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>${war.file.name}</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useFile>false</useFile>
                        <argLine>-Dportal.test=generic
                            -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver"
                            -Dwebdriver.development=true
                            -Dwebdriver.firefox.useExisting=true
                            -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=webdriver
                            -Dwebdriver.reap_profile=true
                            -Dsurefire.useFile=false
                            -Xmx2048M
                            -XX:MaxPermSize=1048M
                            -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
                </argLine>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>

                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>

                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                                <value>META-INF/log4j.xml</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>

                        <includes>
                            <include>cz/instance/transl/tests/selenium/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>cz/instance/transl/tests/sample/*Test.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                    <!-- <configuration> <useFile>false</useFile> </configuration> -->
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </testResource>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>

            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                        <include>service.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                        <include>profiles/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surefire plugin is one that runs by default for a java project. You have a number of options:

- Add the surefire plugin to your `code-generator` profile and override it not to run.
- Run with `-DskipTests`.
- Specify only the goal you want to run, instead of running a full maven build.

Comment: But I cannot run $mvn test:java -PprofileName, right ? It could be done if it was "$mvn somePlugin:java ", not phase:java. How do I specify it ?

Comment: I think you might not be using Maven as it's supposed to be. 'code-generator' sounds like it should be bound to the 'generate-sources' phase. Is it slow or something?

Comment: it is just a simple program that resides in Main method. Not related to code/source generation

Comment: Bind it to a phase before `test`, then, like `compile`.

Comment: Tests will always run for any goals after test, you need to explicitly skip tests if that is your desire. `Run with -DskipTests` is the correct solution here.

Comment: Omg, I didn't think of that :-) Thank you artbristol

Comment: @Gweebz, so that one must declare another surefire plugin in another profile. If you need to run different tests from different profiles for instance. Yes that makes sense